# C++03 equivalent for auto in the context of obtaining an allocator

Tags: c++, auto, allocator

```
auto source_allocator = source.get_allocator();
```

Is there a way of replacing `auto` in the above with something C++03/98-friendly, in the event where the type of allocator is not known in advance?

Comment: No, there is not. You will have to spell out the complete type name. Even `decltype()` wasn't available until C++11, either.

Comment: Under what circumstances is the return type "not known"? It should be in the function signature. Templating is the only thing that springs to mind and, in that case, you could template your own code to match.

Comment: The type is always known in advance. C++ is not a dynamically typed language

Comment: @Taekahn I don't think you understand.
A generically-templated function obtaining an allocator from a given container will not necessarily know the type in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you posted in the comments, it sounds like you're trying to do this inside a template.

Assuming you are expecting your templated type to be a std::container, or something compatible, you can do this:
`typename T::allocator_type` in place of auto.

https://godbolt.org/z/Pda77vjox

Answer (score 2):

At least for standard containers, the container type is required to define `container_type`, so you'd normally end up with something on this general order:

```cpp
template <class Container>
void foo(Container const &source) { 
    typename Container::allocator_type source_allocator = source.get_allocator();
    // ...
}
```

This is exactly the sort of situation for which they required standard containers to define those names. Of course, it also works fine with other containers that do the same.

Comment: This answer is just as good, but have selected Taekahn's for its brevity & clarity.